# using macro to simplify the chapter code to sit on baseline

Tags: chapters

how to customize the coding to get the required output:

1. when chapter title height has less than the the 7\baselineskip, the text after the chapter title should
   start on 12 th line
2. when chapter title height has less than the the 8\baselineskip, the text after the chapter title should
   start on 14 th line

when chapter title increased by one line, then the text should start on the next 16th line and so on.

i have tried with the below coding, but i did with multiple condition, how to simplified the coding without many condition

MWE

```
    \documentclass[openany]{book}

\usepackage{vruler}
\setvruler[12pt][1][1][2][0][32pt][32pt][-1.15pt][\textheight]%%\setvruler[<SCALE>][<INITIAL_COUNT>][<STEP>][<DIGITS>][<MODE>][<ODD_HSHIFT]>][<EVEN_HSHIFT>][<VSHIFT>][<HEIGHT>]

\usepackage{showframe}

\makeatletter



\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \global\setbox\@tempboxa=\vbox{\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
      }%
    \ifdim\ht\@tempboxa<7\baselineskip
        \@tempdima10\baselineskip
        \advance\@tempdima-1.5pt
        \noindent\fboxsep0pt\fboxrule0.1pt\fbox{\vbox to \@tempdima{\unvbox\@tempboxa\vfill}}
    \else%
        \ifdim\ht\@tempboxa<8\baselineskip
        \@tempdima12\baselineskip
        \advance\@tempdima-1.5pt
        \noindent\fboxsep0pt\fboxrule0.1pt\fbox{\vbox to \@tempdima{\unvbox\@tempboxa\vfill}}
    \fi%    
          }

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter Head}

In 2019, Syria experienced its largest outbreak of fires since 2003, when fire occurrence began to be monitored via the MODIS satellite instruments. Here, we combine remotely sensed data on fire, local climatic conditions, and vegetation with spatial data on violence, territorial control, and return of internally displaced persons (IDPs) to explore the underlying causes of Syria's fires at the sub-district, or ADM-3, level. We find evidence for a nuanced story: precipitation and stabilization in Kurdish-controlled territory fueled a bountiful wheat-growing year in 2019. This agricultural resurgence coincided with high fire activity, possibly revealing that people were attempting to jump-start agricultural livelihoods that were lost during the civil war. Restoration of labor forces from IDP returns was not a significant factor in this agricultural recovery. Meanwhile, most sub-districts outside Kurdish-controlled territory were free of fires, which explains the absence of a relationship between vegetation and fire. Thus, Syrian fire patterns in 2019 may be a signal of uneven stabilization, rather than destabilization.

\clearpage

\chapter{Chapter Head turnover into multiline}

In 2019, Syria experienced its largest outbreak of fires since 2003, when fire occurrence began to be monitored via the MODIS satellite instruments. Here, we combine remotely sensed data on fire, local climatic conditions, and vegetation with spatial data on violence, territorial control, and return of internally displaced persons (IDPs) to explore the underlying causes of Syria's fires at the sub-district, or ADM-3, level. We find evidence for a nuanced story: precipitation and stabilization in Kurdish-controlled territory fueled a bountiful wheat-growing year in 2019. This agricultural resurgence coincided with high fire activity, possibly revealing that people were attempting to jump-start agricultural livelihoods that were lost during the civil war. Restoration of labor forces from IDP returns was not a significant factor in this agricultural recovery. Meanwhile, most sub-districts outside Kurdish-controlled territory were free of fires, which explains the absence of a relationship between vegetation and fire. Thus, Syrian fire patterns in 2019 may be a signal of uneven stabilization, rather than destabilization.


n 2019, Syria experienced its largest outbreak of fires since 2003, when fire occurrence began to be monitored via the MODIS satellite instruments. Here, we combine remotely sensed data on fire, local climatic conditions, and vegetation with spatial data on violence, territorial control, and return of internally displaced persons (IDPs) to explore the underlying causes of Syria's fires at the sub-district, or ADM-3, level. We find evidence for a nuanced story: precipitation and stabilization in Kurdish-controlled territory fueled a bountiful wheat-growing year in 2019. This agricultural resurgence coincided with high fire activity, possibly revealing that people were attempting to jump-start agricultural livelihoods that were lost during the civil war. Restoration of labor forces from IDP returns was not a significant factor in this agricultural recovery. Meanwhile, most sub-districts outside Kurdish-controlled territory were free of fires, which explains the absence of a relationship between vegetation and fire. Thus, Syrian fire patterns in 2019 may be a signal of uneven stabilization, rather than destabilization.

n 2019, Syria experienced its largest outbreak of fires since 2003, when fire occurrence began to be monitored via the MODIS satellite instruments. Here, we combine remotely sensed data on fire, local climatic conditions, and vegetation with spatial data on violence, territorial control, and return of internally displaced persons (IDPs) to explore the underlying causes of Syria's fires at the sub-district, or ADM-3, level. We find evidence for a nuanced story: precipitation and stabilization in Kurdish-controlled territory fueled a bountiful wheat-growing year in 2019. This agricultural resurgence coincided with high fire activity, possibly revealing that people were attempting to jump-start agricultural livelihoods that were lost during the civil war. Restoration of labor forces from IDP returns was not a significant factor in this agricultural recovery. Meanwhile, most sub-districts outside Kurdish-controlled territory were free of fires, which explains the absence of a relationship between vegetation and fire. Thus, Syrian fire patterns in 2019 may be a signal of uneven stabilization, rather than destabilization.


\end{document}
```

Comment: why do you need to box and measure at all? You know the font size in advance so can position the baseline without measuring surely?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle based on the chapter title height  need to sit the following text to base line as per my macro this will be done through nested if condition, this need to be simplified like while/for loop

Comment: The only variability is the number of lines in the chapter title and that is the value of `\prevgraf` after `\Huge \bfseries #1\par` so I don't think you need to box and measure anything but no time to provide code answer now sorry.